# Handling protocol inside ISR to avoid atomicity

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I have to handle simple serial protocol. The protocol format is Start byte, Length, Data bytes and Check sum.
I am using UART for data communication. I want to know what is the best way to handle protocol.
In first method, I planned to handle reception inside ISR itself. Checksum validation will not be handled inside ISR. My ISR may look something like below code (Considering generic micro controller). But ISR is little lengthy (Though code is lengthy, there are many if statements and ultimately it may not be too lengthy)

In second method, ISR will just dump the data into a receive buffer and main program will take care of handling the protocol. Though ISR is short, I may have to disable/enable ISR frequently while accessing the Receive buffer from main to avoid atomicity problem. This may lead to performance issues and frequent ISR disable may cause data loss!!

Which is the best method? Any example protocol implementations like this?
Note: The below code is just an outline and not yet tested. There could be few logical errors.

```
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1
#endif // TRUE

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif // TRUE

#define NUM_START_BYTES 1
#define LENGTH_BYTE_POSITION (NUM_START_BYTES)
#define START_BYTE1 0xAA
#define START_BYTE2 0x55
#define END_BYTE 0x0A



#ifdef CHECKSUM_DISABLED
#define CHECKSUM_BYTES 0
#elif defined SIMPLE_CHECKSUM
#define  CHECKSUM_BYTES 1
#else
#define CHECKSUM_BYTES 2
#endif // CHECKSUM_DISABLED


#define NUM_START_BYTES 1
#define LENGTH_BYTE_POSITION (NUM_START_BYTES)
#define START_BYTE1 0xAA
#define START_BYTE2 0x55
#define END_BYTE 0x0A

#define UDR0 0   // Only temporarily declared it as 0. It is actually a register in processor.

enum FRAME_RECEIVE_STATUS
{
    FRAME_SUCCESS=0,
    START_BYTE_RECVD=1,
    RECV_PROGRESS=2,
    FRAME_RECEIVED=3,
    CHECKSUM_ERROR=4,
    FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED=5,
};

volatile enum FRAME_RECEIVE_STATUS frameStatus=FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED;

#define RX_MAX_SIZE 32 // size for received data buffer.

volatile uint8_t RxData[RX_MAX_SIZE];
volatile uint8_t RxHead=0;              // Initialize the RxHead to 0
volatile uint8_t frameLength=0;         // Overall length of the received data


/**RX Complete interrupt service routine
// Receive the data and write to  buffer if buffer is not full
Initially frameStatus=FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED;
This protocol supports, 0, 1 or 2 start bytes and indicated by NUM_START_BYTES

As soon as first START_BYTE is verified, frameStatus changes to START_BYTE_RECVD.
As soon as second start byte is received, frameStatus changes to RECV_PROGRESS.
That means as soon as START Bytes are verified (It could be 0 1 or 2), frameStatus changes to RECV_PROGRESS

Packet Format:
Start Byte1 (optional), Start byte2 (optional), Length=n, data bytes = n-check sum bytes, one or two check sum bytes

Length includes data bytes and check sum
Checksum may be 0, 1 or 2 bytes and indicated by CHECKSUM_BYTES field
*/

void myRxISR()
{

    // If buffer is full, we cannot transfer data. We probably want to discard the data if buffer is full.
    // Yet to decide on this
    if(RxHead<RX_MAX_SIZE)
    {
        RxData[RxHead++]=UDR0;
        frameLength++;
        if(frameStatus==RECV_PROGRESS) //Packet reception is already started
        {
            // We need to check if all bytes including checksum is received
            //First verify the length field. Length field is immediately after START_BYTE fields
            if(frameLength==CHECKSUM_BYTES+1)
            {
                //Minimum 1 byte must be there in any command excluding check sum
                // In case the data length is less than 1+checksum bytes,
                //we need to completely discard the transaction.
                // Length is available in RxData[NUM_START_BYTES]
                if(RxData[NUM_START_BYTES]<CHECKSUM_BYTES+1)
                {
                    frameStatus=FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED;  // Discard the data
                    RxHead=0;  // Clear the received data buffer
                }
            }
            else   // Length is already received and verified. Receive other data bytes and CS
            {

                // Once the length is received, we need to count as many bytes as length
                //and receive the complete the frame.

                if(frameLength >= RxData[NUM_START_BYTES]+NUM_START_BYTES+1)   //1 for length field itself
                {
                    // Finished receiving the complete frame
                    //At the end, frameRecived flag must be set.
                    frameStatus=FRAME_RECEIVED;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Nothing needs to be done. Just data bytes are being received
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if START_BYTE is present in this protocol or not.
            // This code supports 0, 1 or 2 start bytes.
            if(NUM_START_BYTES)
            {
                //First wait for the first START_BYTE. If first START_BYTE is received,
                // check if second start byte is present and verify the second start byte.
                // As soon as first start byte is received, status changes to START_BYTE_RECVD

                if((frameStatus==START_BYTE_RECVD))
                {
                    // first byte is received already. This is the second byte
                    // Need to verify the second Byte in case there are two bytes
                    // In case there is only one start byte, control will not come here anyway

                    if(RxData[RxHead-1]==START_BYTE2)
                    {
                        frameStatus=RECV_PROGRESS;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Discard data
                        RxHead=0;
                        frameStatus=FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED;
                    }
                }
                else  // Just First start Byte is received
                {
                    if(RxData[RxHead-1]==START_BYTE1)
                    {
                        if(NUM_START_BYTES>1)  // 2 start bytes only possible in this protocol
                        {
                            // We need to wait for start byte2 next
                            frameStatus=START_BYTE_RECVD;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Only one start byte. So start byte reception is successful
                            frameStatus=RECV_PROGRESS;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Discard data
                        RxHead=0;
                        //frameStatus already FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED
                        //frameStatus=FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED;
                    }
                }
            }
            else  // NUM_START_BYTES=0. Means we directly start reception without any start bytes
            {
                frameStatus=RECV_PROGRESS;
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //In case buffer is full, we need to see what to do.
        // May be discard the data received.
        frameStatus=FRAME_NOT_RECEIVED;  // Discard the data
        RxHead=0;  // Clear the received data buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to research *ring buffers* or *queues*.

Comment: No need to disable the isr, simply use a ringbuffer with a write-. and a readpointer. You just have to handle a possible overflow correctly

Comment: Leave the isr code as short (in time) as possible is always the best idea.

Comment: Note with a simple MCU you will not be able to make sure a full frame is received (i.e. "already there") when your ISR is called. You might be ending up **needing to wait** for bytes in the ISR which is not a very good idea...

Answer (score 3):

Overall, this depends on your requirements. If you have hard real-time requirements stating that your program must respond very quickly to the received data, or if errors in the data must get flagged immediately, then putting decoding inside the ISR might make some sense. It won't be pretty though.

Rare cases with such requirements do exist, I've done a project with such requirements once. But far more likely, you don't have such requirements.

Then the first thing to look at is if your UART peripheral got support for DMA. If so, then you should utilize it and have the DMA shovel in the data into RAM for you. This is the best method.

If you don't have DMA support, then you need to check how big a receive buffer you have. Depending on its size, you could perhaps poll the receive buffer repeatedly. This is always to prefer before interrupts when possible - polling is the second best method.

If you don't have a large receive buffer, or if the main program is busy with a lot of other things, then you'll have to resort to interrupts. Note that interrupts should always be the last choice to consider, when you have no other options. They are problematic for real-term performance, they are bug-prone, they are tricky to program... they are evil in general.

If you have a large receive buffer, you could reduce the number of interrupts triggered by only responding to buffer full flags.

You should minimize the interrupt length as much as possible. As mentioned in comments, you're going to want a ring buffer ADT that can quickly store down data without too much overhead.

You also have to sort out re-entrancy between the ISR and the caller code, since they will both access the ring buffer. This can be handled with semaphores or by enabling/disabling interrupts, or by utilizing the fact that the ISR can't get interrupted by the main program etc. This is highly system-specific.

Essentially the ISR should look like this pseudo:

```
interrupt void UART_ISR (void)
{
  check interrupt source if needed

  if interrupt was rx data
  {
    check/grab ring buffer semaphore
    store rx buffer inside ringbuffer ADT
    release ring buffer semaphore
  }
  clear relevant flags
}
```

Then in the caller, you check/grab the ring buffer semaphore, copy the contents into a local buffer, release the semaphore and then get down to protocol decoding.

Keeping protocol decoding completely separate from the ISR gives a clean design with a minimum of interrupt latency. It is also good OO design, because if you make changes to the hardware timing, it won't affect the protocol, or if you make changes to the protocol, you don't have to re-write the ISR. You get a loose coupling between the driver and the protcol.

In addition, as you have already realized, CRC calculations can chew up some execution time, so it is good to keep those away from ISRs too.

As a side note, you need some form of error handling for buffer overruns, framing errors etc. These may be available as separate flags/interrupts. Do implement such error handling!

Comment: Good idea to preserve this answer into documentation. This kind of question is asked frequently.

Comment: Yeah, this. I've used this approach of making the ISR as simple as possible on very small embedded microprocessors. 16-byte ring buffer on a 16-byte address boundary, wrap around just using "& 0x0f", and there's no need for semaphores when the ISR only modifies the 'write' pointer and the mainline only modifies the 'read' pointer. At most primitve make sure the mainline consumed the data quickly enough - or better to make ISR check for overlap of read/write pointers and discard more rx data, mainline if pointers overlap, sets rdptr=wrptr and discards anything partly decoded.

Comment: @barny There is always a need for semaphores if you share variables with an ISR. Alternatively, find out a way to guarantee that all access is atomic. Consider for example the case where the buffer is full, you start to read data, get interrupted halfways through the read, new data is written to the location you were reading from - you end up with garbage data and subtle intermittent bugs.

Comment: That's the point of making the ISR only modify the write pointer and the mainline only modify the read pointer - no need for a semaphore because no variable that both sides modify. Make the ISR NEVER overfill the buffer, and make the mainline ALWAYS act robustly when it detects a full buffer, i.e. Assume some data has been lost. On that basis there isn't a shared variable (one that both write to) so no need for semaphore.

Comment: @barny And how can you detect if the buffer is full or not? By reading a shared size variable, which is not necessarily updated atomically. Alternatively, by calculating it based on the read and write pointer offsets, in which case both sides have to access both pointers. What it all boils down to is that this is a generic scenario where an ISR needs to communicate something with main. In every single such case, the communication needs to be done through atomic variables or through thread safety constructs. There exists no magic way around it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to handle simple serial protocol ... Start, Length, Data, Checksum.

**Basing on your info, I would say to manage all in ISR.**

Especially if the protocol is of the type poll-reply, you can use a single buffer and signal the foreground that a packet has been received, waiting to be processed. The data will stay there.

Consider this: everything you do to receive a character, has to be done anyway (not considering DMA). The total "power" of the CPU is stressed the same. So, from that point of view, it is the same to manage the protocol in ISR or not.

The more you do in ISR, the more "spreading" of CPU power results. Or, in other words, delays are spreaded - many small delays instead of fewer but longer. If receiving a packet is heavy for the CPU: by using ISR your program will be overall slower, but without long pauses - not using ISR will make the program faster, but more sluggish. Note that "heavy for the CPU". I don't think your protocol is heavy, but I don't know.

The third and last problem: does the ISR steal reactivity to other ISRs?. If yes, we want this ISR to be as fast as possible (fast, *not* short). But often there is the possibility to prioritize ISRs, so the problem is almost gone.

What I said above is purely technical. Some other answers here talks about clarity, coding style, separation between "receiving" and "work on received data". Important things, but I am not considering that.

So to conclude, I would say that implementing the whole protocol *inside* an ISR is not bad. Moreover, the CRC calculation could be made inside the ISR, step by step (probably it is possible). This way, instead of receiving all the packet, then re-reading it to calculate the checksum, the checksum would be ready to be checked as soon as the packet is complete. "More spreading".

Using ring-buffers, semaphores, *copying data* in local buffers, are all method to waste resources and time, if not needed. If we are low in resources, we have to save them. If we have plenty of them, then there is no problem anyway. This is not to say that those methods are wrong, but simply this: are they really needed? Especially in a microcontroller (not exactly an internet server)?

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is defined by the user/reader it is not universal.  So only you can answer what the "best method" is for you.

You could create a state machine in the ISR that for each byte that comes in could relatively quickly based on state, perform a very short operation.  Save byte in buffer add to checksum if at length bump state otherwise dont, return.

or a faster state machine that just saves the byte in a buffer and returns.

In both cases (although based on your system design you could possibly do a lot more in the isr) you likely have the application polling for new packets.  Depending on your system design the isr may have done all the work isolating and checksumming (or crc) the packet so the foreground only has to operate on it.  that or the other extreme the foreground has to do all this work the isr only fills the head of a circular buffer.

What you have to decide to determine what best is, is in your system design, what is your real time requirements, how long worst case can you tolerate being held off by an isr.  and/or other interrupts that are coming in how often do the come in, is there a regular timer that cannot be held off too long and/or does your system have a priority scheme for interrupts so that the serial receive isr can be interrupted by a high priority timer isr, etc.

Basically just do your system engineering and all these answers just fall out of that.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have a design that is heavy on the foreground side, and likewise one that is heavy if not completely interrupt based, where all the code/work is in the interrupt handler(s).  Just depends on your system design, in either case you need to know all and the worst case paths through your isr and insure they fit within the system design.